# Unity Configuration using multiple config files

Tags: web-config, unity-container, configuration-files

Is there a way to configure a container in multiple configuration files?

For instance, I want to register types for a container in a web.config file located at the root and also register types for the same container (and others containers) in the web.config file of sub-folders.

And also register other types for others containers in a company.config file in path C:\Company\Framework\Configs.

When I try to do this I get a ConfigurationError stating that the entry for the container has already been added.

EDIT: any suggestions here
http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=23230

any more suggestions for sample code ?

Comment: how did you tried to do this?

Comment: i have several configs for unity, one of them in web.config, and when I try "load" unity config from another file (using Locator and UnityContainer), then I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question posted here: [WCF + Unity nested web.config problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4439629/541900)

I have a web application with a subdirectory 'Services' which contains WCF services.
This services folder also has a web.config file containing my WCF configuration. That doesn't seem to be a problem for WCF.

The same web.config also has unity configuration for use inside my services. But i'm unable to load this configuration using 'GetSection'

If I move my unity configuration to the root web.config, everythings works fine.

Comment: I have much applications in company, and there are unity components shared for all appllications, and unity components ONLY using for one application, each application has his unity components. Therefore, we need several unity config files.